# Error 404 GET Image when I use AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am programming a personal website with AngularJS (for my training). I use the Carousel from [UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) like this :

HTML:

```
 <carousel interval="interval" no-wrap="false">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{slide.image}}">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>{{slide.text}}</h4>
            </div>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('myWebSiteApp')
.controller('HikingCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.interval = 4000;
    $scope.slides = [{
        image: '/images/background/bg15.jpg',
        text: 'Chiemsee Lake - Baviera'
    }, {
        image: '/images/background/bg13.jpg',
        text: 'Plansee Lake - Austria'
    },{
        image: '/images/background/bg8.jpg',
        text: 'Sentier des Roches'
    },{
        image: '/images/background/bg10.jpg',
        text: 'Hochplatte - Baviera'
    }];
});
```

When I test this code in local it works but when I upload the website on the server it does not work...
I have an error 404:
[image]

Moreover, if I use the images without JS but with css it works.

EDIT:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Ysee

Comment: are you hosting your site with and previewing it in the root of your domain?

Comment: Using "/" at the beginning of your url means "root folder". Are you sure your image locations are like "mydomain.com/images/background/bg10.jpg"

Comment: So check the actual path being used.

Comment: I have added a image. The image path is good.

Comment: I guess you can access the path that js is producing if you copy it into the browser

Comment: It's interesting, I get the image with the full path into the browser (http://yseemonnier.com/images/background/bg10.33dfa270.jpg). But I also use this image for an background using CSS (url:images/background/bg10.jpg). url is totaly different but the result is the same...

Comment: Hmmm, I think what you need is to add the absolute file path by including the www before the "/images". Something like "/www/images/background/bg15.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rework your application build process. Obviously images have been revisioned, as `bg15.jpg` became `bg15.284af477.jpg`. But the step which ***replace*** the original image files in the application code with the revisioned image file is missing.

Let's assume you are using `gulp`, and image revisioning have been done with [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev). You might want to look at [gulp-rev-replace](https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace) for rewriting occurences of revisioned assets.

Comment: Yes thank you. When I delete the revision from the Gruntfile it works. YM